# Schedule a Process in C# to run 24*7

Tags: process, c#-3.0, scheduler

I have a business critical application which needs to run 24*7. Right now its scheduled using Windows Task Scheduler. The problem with current implementation is whenever the application stops it has to wait for 1 minute to run again.(Since one minute is the minimum time to repeat task in Windows Task Scheduler) So I am building my own task scheduler which will start the process(application) within 5 seconds of terminating the process. How should my task scheduler know if the process has terminated. Do I need to keep polling the process every second to check whether its running or not?

Answer (score 3):

You should write your application as a [Windows Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service), not a standard application.

Among their other advantages, Windows Services give you the ability to define what happens in the event of a failure (e.g. restart application).

They are also [very easy to create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) in C#.